# How to configue expressjs to serve index.html in production mode?

Tags: node.js, production

I am trying to deploy my app to my local computer to simulate the deployment process. You call it staging mode or whatever. Tools I used include pm2 and Nginx.

I am able to use my web app when I run my app using `pm2 start server.js` directly in my project. The client can access the `index.html` file though a Nginx server. But I think this is not production mode unless I also use `--env production`.

So I copy all the required files to the `dist` directory of my project, configured Nginx to serve the static contents, and in my source code, I want to use

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: somePath});
});
```

to allow the clients to access the `index.html` file on express server. But I am not sure what to put in `somePath`? I separate the server side and client side when I deploy my project to the server. For example, my server side is on `/usr/path/server` but my client side is on `/etc/shared/html`. If I mess up with the paths I will get a "forbidden" error message from 
express when I access `index.html`.

Comment: i think you should use this
https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko I am using Nginx to serve static contents. Why should I use this module?

Answer (score 0):

If you want make production-like repeatability during development, then you should implement same functionality with same tools.

Nowadays [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is best solution for resolve this issue. As start you should have two container the first with nginx and the second with pm2. Also you should bind/mount volume for static files to nginx.

Comment: Yes I am planning to use docker later. But at this stage I need to put it onto internet quickly.

Comment: In my opinion docker compose is the simplest solution for demonstrating your application in production like style. If you need something more quick and dirty, then you can use code-hacks (for example: serve-static from @ArtemIlchenko advice) or simple and free tools for publishing in internet (for example: https://c9.io)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this.

```
 var path = require('path');
 var virtualDirPath = process.env.virtualDirPath || '';
 var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename) + virtualDirPath;
```

appDir will give the **environment directory**, from where you can access the `html` file.

Hope it helps:)